# Copyright cover art question

Tags: copyright

Is hand drawing a picture of a copyrighted cover art legal? I do not intend to use it for selling, the public, or anything of the like.

Comment: If you’re not selling it or showing it in public, what *are* you doing with it?

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't selling anything, aren't using it publicly for any reason, and aren't otherwise profiting from it's display. It would most likely fall under **[fair use](https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/more-info.html)** principles.

It's probably fine to use. There's not much more that can be stated without more details. It would be [derivative work](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/derivative_work), but again, sounds like perfectly fine fair use.